# I am trying to convert date in Dart. But I am getting a date one day before the specified date. How to solve this error and reason for this?

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, dart-null-safety

```
print(json["end"] + " date before parsing");
print(DateTime.parse(json["end"]).toString() + " date after parsing");
```

Output

```
I/flutter ( 7101): 2022-07-19T05:00:00+05:30 date before parsing
I/flutter ( 7101): 2022-07-18 23:30:00.000Z date after parsing
```

As you can see, the date before parsing is 19-07-2022
but after parsing it, the date I am getting is 18-07-2022.
Why is this happening, and how to solve this?

Comment: The original date/time is in a local time.  The parsed one shows the corresponding UTC date/time.

Answer (score 1):

From your response, you can check you're getting the time (current Date&Time of your system + +5:30) so try to use `.toUtc()` or something because your time is 5 hr 30 min less that's why you're getting one day before.

Comment: `.toUtc()` wouldn't change anything.  The parsed `DateTime` is *already* UTC.